is impossible misses

Affection in the sense of a genuine reciprocal interest of two persons
in each other, not solely as means to each other’s good, but rather as
a combination having a common good, is one of the most important
elements of real happiness, and the man whose ego is so enclosed
within steel walls that this enlargement of it is impossible misses
the best that life has to offer, however successful he may be in his
career.

It's from Russell's essay on happiness, I had trouble understanding it while reading it. What does this part "and the man whose ego is so enclosed within steel walls that this enlargement of it is impossible misses the best that life has to offer" mean? I wonder if there's something left out? I don't understand the word "misses”; I would have understood it if there was a comma before "misses".

Yes, there should be a comma.

There's absolutely no requirement for a comma before "misses" - it would be a mistake to include it. The text the man whose ego is so enclosed within steel walls that this enlargement of it is impossible is simply a long complicated noun phrase. If such a type of person had been already been identified in previous text, it could be replaced by Affection ... is one of the most important elements of real happiness, and such a man [one with an ego so constrained it can't get any bigger] misses the best that life has to offer [, even if he seems successful]. No comma.

@FumbleFingers - "a long complicated noun phrase" - good old Russell! He wrote, with relish, of an occasion where a drunk stood up and interrupted a speech by Mr Gladstone. This latter fixed the miscreant with his steely gaze and said' I can assure the gentleman who has ventured to interrupt me, that if our positions were reversed, I should unfailingly show him the courtesy that he has not shown to me'. It is said that the man sat down stone cold sober.

@MichaelHarvey: I have a vague memory of an insanely convoluted "Order Note for Milkman" that I always thought was attributed to Russell. But Google can't find it for me now, so if it ever existed it probably didn't come from him anyway.

Parse it like this:

the man (whose ego is so enclosed within steel walls that this enlargement of it is impossible) misses (the best that life has to offer).

In other words, the long phrase "whose ego is so enclosed within steel walls that this enlargement of it is impossible" describes "the man". The "misses" is then the main verb, and "the best that life has to offer" is the object of that verb, ie the thing that he is missing.

This is a good parse.

The last part should be ... object of that verb.

What you really meant was “the object” rather than the subject, right Daniel?

Yes you're right, sorry - corrected.

The structure is like this:

... so big that fitting the item in the box is impossible
... so hot that drinking it is impossible
... so quick that capturing it on film is difficult

so {adjective} that {verb}ing it is {adjective}
Once you are familiar with that use of so + gradable adjective and the structure of the complementing that-clause, you will not be thrown by lack of punctuation.  The contour of the clause itself will guide you:

A man who is so thirsty that he does care that a cup of tea is so hot that drinking it is impossible risks burning his mouth.

